# How to find the power dissapation of a resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law, troubleshooting, power-dissipation, dc-ac

I am attempting to repair a circuit (DC-AC inverter) and have incountered a resistor with discolouration.

The measurements indicte a resistance of 1.5Mohms or usually OL leading me to belive the resistor is dead.

[image: zone 1 picture]

Would i be correct in thinking that from the colour bands, the resistor should be 310ohms?

Also, is its size because of the power dissipation of this particular resistor?

I have checked the componants within the circuit as follows 
[image: Zone 1 checked]

In order to find the power dissipation of the resistor i have used ohms law as follows; 
[image: Ohms law calculations]

Does this look correct or am i missing somthing fundamental?

Many thanks 
Tony

Comment: The flash has washed out the band colors, but 310 is not a member of E24 regardless.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you draw the part of the circuit that the resistor is part of, to deduce its functionality. Based on the image I would say it is a 810Ω resistor.

Comment: It looks like grey brown brown gold making it 810R 5%

Comment: Error in you formula. It should read \$ P = VI = \frac {V^2}{R} \$. You didn't use the last part anyway so your calculation result is correct.

Comment: What is it connected between?

Comment: I noticed that from the 310. 300 or 330 being the closed match i could use to that. The resistor is connected between a coil and a thermistor. Its difficult to see from the images. Im drawing somthing up at the moment. Thanks for your help and all the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grey-brown-brown-gold indicates an 810 ohm 5% resistor.

I = V/R = 24/810 = ~30mA

P = IV = 30mA * 24 = 720mW

It looks like it's a 1W resistor.

Edit: It could possibly be a 910 ohm resistor (white-brown-brown) which is part of the E24 set of values. It would still need to be a 1W resistor.

Comment: Which is also not an E24 value.

Comment: It is unusual but E24 are not the only resistors.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will look into using a 910 1W resistor within the circuit. Bitshift, your answer makes a lot of sense, thank you very much